# Amazon Customer Questions & Answers: we can't answer customers anymore

Tags: amazon

For example, [here](https://www.amazon.co.uk/ask/questions/Tx1MA4ED2PJI7P0/ref=ask_ql_ql_al_hza)

The customer is asking: Is it compatible with Samsung galaxy J4plus

But I just can’t answer because Amazon returns the error: “To post, accounts need to have a minimum amount of valid purchases. Prime subscriptions and promotional discounts don’t qualify”

I’m the seller and I used to be able to answer the customers without any problem. So not sure why it’s not possible now!

The only person from Amazon customer support who seems to understand the problem/question told us that we receive the error message because we are not using the link provided in our notification email. But have NOT received any notification email.

I've checked https://sellercentral-europe.amazon.com/notifications/preferences as well. All email notifications are enabled except:  Amazon Fulfilment Order Notifications and Multichannel Fulfillment Notifications. So it seems correct.

We only receive notifications to answer private messages, not public messages.

Any idea to be able to answer customers?